# Why isnt the APScheduler executing all of the code?

Tags: python, apscheduler

```
import nflgame

import csv

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

year = 2013

week = 1

games = nflgame.games(year, week)

players = nflgame.combine_game_stats(games)

ctr = 0

def myjob():
    print('This job is run every 2 seconds.')

with open('/Users/lukenolan/Desktop/Python Work/data.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write('%s,%s %s' % (str(year), str(week), '\n'))
    for p in players:
        print(ctr)
        ctr += 1
        file.write('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (p.playerid, p.player.position, p.name, p.team, p.passing_att, p.passing_cmp, p.passing_yds, p.passing_tds, p.passing_ints, p.passing_sk, p.passing_twoptm, p.passing_yds, p.rushing_att, p.rushing_yds, p.rushing_tds, p.rushing_twoptm, p.rushing_yds_loss, p.receiving_rec, p.receiving_twoptm, p.receiving_yds, p.receiving_tds, p.fumbles_tot, p.fumbles_lost, p.fumbles_rec, p.defense_frec, p.defense_sk, p.defense_int, p.defense_tds, p.defense_safe, p.kicking_fgd, p.punting_blk, p.defense_xpblk, p.kicking_fgm_yards, p.kicking_xpmade, p.kicking_fgmissed))
        file.write('\n')

sched = BackgroundScheduler()

sched.add_job(myjob, 'interval', seconds=5)

sched.start()
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail about which part of the code isn't being executed and what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is, like in so many other cases, is that you're starting a background scheduler and then letting the script exit. This is precisely what `BlockingScheduler` is for.